# Gatsby website built but 'UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined at parseError' when opening localhost

Tags: npm, gatsby, strapi

My gatsby website was running locally without problems and when I tried to restart it today without updating the code, the npm run develop build succeeds. However, when I try to open localhost in browser, this error is thrown in the terminal:

```
success Building development bundle - 16.014s
success Writing page-data.json files to public directory - 0.103s - 3/11
106.93/s

(node:2043) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at parseError (/Users/sp/Documents/jamstack/training/frontend/node_modules/gatsby/src/utils/dev-ssr/render-dev-html-child.js:52:26)
    at /Users/sp/Documents/jamstack/training/frontend/node_modules/gatsby/src/utils/dev-ssr/render-dev-html-child.js:106:27
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:2043) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejeæction, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:2043) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I can't seem to work out where this error is coming from as I did not change any of the code that was working earlier.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

There's no detail about the running version of Gatsby but according to this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/30780#issuecomment-817180215), while the issue is being fixed in the next release you can bypass it by installing a canary version:

```
npm i gatsby@webpack-split-fix
```